# Converting static code into reusable D3.js pie animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to rework a pen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgyCz) by Travis Palmer so that I can use it on multiple elements. We are trying to place several `<div class="donut" data-donut="x">`'s on a page.

**So it would look similar to the html below:**

```
////// HTML 

<div class="donut" data-donut="22"></div>

<div class="donut" data-donut="48"></div>

<div class="donut" data-donut="75></div>
```

**The D3.js / jQuery example I'm trying to convert to a reusable compunent is below. (To see full working example go to this link - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgyCz)**

```
////// D3.js

var duration   = 500,
    transition = 200;

drawDonutChart(
  '.donut',
  $('.donut').data('donut'),
  290,
  290,
  ".35em"
);

function drawDonutChart(element, percent, width, height, text_y) {
  width = typeof width !== 'undefined' ? width : 290;
  height = typeof height !== 'undefined' ? height : 290;
  text_y = typeof text_y !== 'undefined' ? text_y : "-.10em";

  var dataset = {
        lower: calcPercent(0),
        upper: calcPercent(percent)
      },
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
      pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null),
      format = d3.format(".0%");

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 20)
        .outerRadius(radius);

  var svg = d3.select(element).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(dataset.lower))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "color" + i })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial values

  var text = svg.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", text_y);

  if (typeof(percent) === "string") {
    text.text(percent);
  }
  else {
    var progress = 0;
    var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      path = path.data(pie(dataset.upper)); // update the data
      path.transition().duration(duration).attrTween("d", function (a) {
        // Store the displayed angles in _current.
        // Then, interpolate from _current to the new angles.
        // During the transition, _current is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
        var i  = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
        var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, percent)
        this._current = i(0);
        return function(t) {
          text.text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
          return arc(i(t));
        };
      }); // redraw the arcs
    }, 200);
  }
};

function calcPercent(percent) {
  return [percent, 100-percent];
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured it out. I feel a bit dumb in hindsight, but what can I say, I'm a js n00b. All you have to do is make a few more call to the drawDonutChart() method. In short:

```
drawDonutChart(
  '#donut1',
  $('#donut1').data('donut'),
  220,
  220,
  ".35em"
);

drawDonutChart(
  '#donut2',
  $('#donut2').data('donut'),
  120,
  120,
  ".35em"
);

drawDonutChart(
  '#donut3',
  $('#donut3').data('donut'),
  150,
  150,
  ".2em"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use angular directives.  An angular directive basically wraps html inside a custom tag and let's you stamp the directive over and over across multiple pages or multiple times a page.  See this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqHBLS_6gF8

There is also a library that is out called nvd3.js that contains prebuilt angular directives that can be re-used: http://nvd3.org/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your response but both Angular and nvd3 are a bit much for my purposes. We're relying on too many frameworks etc. as it is. Worse case scenario I could just clone the code and just change the names.